# How to use left join with Where clause

Tags: mysql, join

I was thinking that I have a very good understanding about my sql and joins but i miserably failed to make this query. I have to make employee leave report, therefore I want all employee list no matter he make leave or not, if there is no leave then zero will be displayed. I have this query currently:

```
select
leave_detail_id, emp_id, Employee_Name, leave_type, leave_name, sum(leave_total_days) total_leave, leave_current_status_id
from employee emp
left join  tbl_emp_leave_details eld
ON emp.PK = eld.emp_id
inner join tbl_leave_types lt
ON lt.leave_id = eld.leave_type
where leave_current_status_id = 1
and leave_start_date >= '01-07-2019'
and leave_end_date <= '31-07-2019'
```

and emp.Active=1
    group by leave_type

You can see that even after applying left join i am unable to bring all the employees. Please help me to understand the problem. I know that where filter is also apply to join. but how can i correct this with (an explanation)?

Comment: select
leave_detail_id, emp_id, Employee_Name, leave_type, leave_name, sum(leave_total_days) total_leave, leave_current_status_id
from employee emp
left join  tbl_emp_leave_details eld
ON  eld.emp_id  = emp.PK
inner join tbl_leave_types lt
ON lt.leave_id = eld.leave_type
where leave_current_status_id = 1
and leave_start_date >= '01-07-2019'
and leave_end_date <= '31-07-2019'    
 - the employee table all data u view?

Comment: @KGR Sorry this brought the same result.

Comment: give the table structure.

Comment: which table strucutre?

Comment: your 3 table structure.

Comment: When you write `... FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.x=t2.y WHERE t2.z = something AND ...` you in practice obtain INNER JOIN instead of LEFT. Such conditions (by joined table fields, exclusion - checking for IS NULL) must be placed into ON clause: `... FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON (t1.x=t2.y AND t2.z = something) WHERE ...`

Comment: `leave_start_date >= '01-07-2019'` does not work.  Make sure `leave_start_date` is datatype `DATE` _and_ say `'2019-07-01'`

Comment: date is the data type of both leave start and end column. I guess this is not the issue . The issue is sum function in  select.

Answer (score 1):

You might try this, however as I do not have any understanding of your schema, the result might not be what you search for.

```
select
  leave_detail_id
  ,emp_id
  ,Employee_Name
  ,leave_type
  ,leave_name
  ,sum(leave_total_days) total_leave
  ,leave_current_status_id
from employee emp
left join  tbl_emp_leave_details eld
  ON emp.PK = eld.emp_id
left join tbl_leave_types lt
  ON lt.leave_id = eld.leave_type
  and leave_current_status_id = 1
  and leave_start_date >= '01-07-2019'
  and leave_end_date <= '31-07-2019'
group by 
  leave_detail_id
  ,emp_id
  ,Employee_Name
  ,leave_type
  ,leave_name
  ,leave_current_status_id
```

Comment: not this brought the same result.

Comment: this will for sure bring all the employees .. I do not know if the data calculated will be ok

Comment: I don't know but i have run this query and still getting only single record(emp).

Comment: Can you please share the 3 table structure?

Comment: oh actually i find that sum fuction in the select is the problem.

Comment: (Fix the date format, too.)

Comment: @RickJames It is already date type column. The problem is sum function which i don't know how to use with all records. The sum function restricting non matched records.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan - you cannot get correct comparisons with wrongly formatted date literals.  See my Comment under your question.  You will probably be `SUMming` more rows than you expect.

Comment: I added the "group by" at the end. Please check to see if it is what you need. Would be good to have the schemas and expectations, otherwise would be a guessing game :D